# Solving $6200 = (x \times 10000)/(x + 10000)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation: 
$$6200 = (x \times 10000)/(x + 10000)$$

I managed to solve using Microsoft Mathematics. The value is $16,315.7894$. I would like to know how to solve it on paper.

I found that a part of the equation is 
$$6200/2 \times 10,000 \quad\text{or}\quad 6200 / (10000/2) = 31,000,000$$

The result of $16,315.7894 = 31,000,000 / 1900$.

How do I get 1900?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: thank you guys!

To resume: x = 6200*10000/ (10000-6200) = 16.315,7894

lack of study and logic ... kkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you started with $6200 = \dfrac{(x\cdot 10000)}{(x+10000)}$

Assume that $x\neq -10000$ (*else you have a division by zero in the above*) and multiply both sides by $(x+10000)$ to clear out the fraction on the other side.  That gives us

$$6200\cdot (x+10000) = \dfrac{(x\cdot 10000)}{(x+10000)}\cdot (x+10000)$$

or simplified:

$$6200x + 62000000 = 10000x$$

From here, subtract $6200x$ from each side so that you are left with a variable only on one side of the equation and raw numbers on the other.  You get:

$$62000000 = 3800x$$

Now, just divide both sides by $3800$ and you are done, giving as a final answer

$$x=\frac{62000000}{3800} \approx 16315.789\dots$$

If your question is why we could have written $x$ as $\frac{31000000}{1900}$... that is by dividing top and bottom of the denominator by the same value of $2$.  It is just a fancy way of multiplying by $1$ which of course doesn't change the value of anything.  You can think of it as $$\frac{62000000}{3800}\cdot 1=\frac{62000000}{3800}\cdot\frac{1/2}{1/2}=\frac{62000000/2}{3800/2} = \frac{31000000}{1900}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your given equation
$$
\frac{10^5x}{10^5+x}-6200=0
$$
is equivalent to
$$
38x-620000=0.
$$
So we have
$$
x=\frac{620000}{38}=\frac{2^5\cdot 5^4\cdot 31}{2\cdot 19}=\frac{310000}{19}.
$$
This gives your $19$, or $1900$.

Answer (score 1):

$$6200=\frac{10000x}{x+10000}.$$ Multiply $x+10000$ on both sides: $$6200(x+10000)=6200x+62000000=10000x.$$ Subtract $6200x$ on both sides: $$62000000=10000x-6200x=3800x.$$ Divide $3800$ on both sides:$$\frac{62000000}{3800}=x.$$